# Instruct Automake to use C++ compiler for *.S files?

Tags: c++, autotools, automake

We have a C++ project. We need to assemble a `*.S` file through the compiler. In our `GNUmakefile` we use:

```
# ARM asm implementation.
aes-armv4.o : aes-armv4.S
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(AES_FLAGS) -mfloat-abi=$(FP_ABI) -c $<
```

We have the following in our `Makefile.am`, which depends on `AC_SUBST([AES_FLAGS], [-march=armv7-a -Wa,--noexecstack])` in `configure.ac`:

```
libaes_armv4_la_SOURCES = aes-armv4.S
libaes_armv4_la_CXXFLAGS = $(AM_CXXFLAGS) $(AES_FLAGS)
```

However, the resulting `Makefile` uses the `C` compiler and fails to use the flags we setup for the source file:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/build/cryptopp'
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -g -O2 -MT aes-armv4.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/aes-armv4.Tpo -c -o aes-armv4.lo aes-armv4.S
libtool: compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -g -O2 -MT aes-armv4.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/aes-armv4.Tpo -c aes-armv4.S -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/aes-armv4.o
libtool: compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -g -O2 -MT aes-armv4.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/aes-armv4.Tpo -c aes-armv4.S -o aes-armv4.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/aes-armv4.Tpo .deps/aes-armv4.Plo
```

`AES_FLAGS` provides `-march=armv7-a -Wa,--noexecstack`. `-march=armv7-a` increases performance due to unaligned loads and `-Wa,--noexecstack` is a security requirement.

The manual does not state how to tell Autotools to use the C++ compiler in this instance. Also see [8.9 C++ Support](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/C_002b_002b-Support.html).

How do I tell Automake to use the C++ compiler and flags for the source file?

---

Our `configure.ac` has the following. It lacks a reference to the C compiler and never touches `AC_PROG_CC`, `CFLAGS` or `AM_CFLAGS` because we are a C++ project:

```
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_LANG([C++])

...
AC_SUBST([AES_FLAGS], [-march=armv7-a -Wa,--noexecstack])
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Assembly-Support.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

automake uses the `CCAS` macro to specify which compiler to run, using `CCASFLAGS` and `AM_CCASFLAGS` to specify any custom compilation options.

[More information](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Assembly-Support.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
# Old-style (but portable) inference rules for assembler and C++
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .s .S .sx .o .cpp .cc .C .cxx .c++ .cp

.S.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(AES_FLAGS) -mfloat-abi=$(FP_ABI) -c $<

######## OR ########

# GNU make pattern rule syntax
%.o: %.S
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(AES_FLAGS) -mfloat-abi=$(FP_ABI) -c $<
```

If you're using GNU make, then it doesn't matter which one you choose, but you should be aware of the usage and limitations of POSIX inference rules [(GNU make calls them "suffix rules")](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html), including the fact that they cannot have any dependencies (else they're considered normal targets) and the fact that your suffixes must be predefined.

The `make` implementations I've used have a default set of rules for C++ and sometimes even additional extensions for certain implementation-specific features, such as compiling to assembler code, in addition to [the default rules prescribed by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html#tag_20_76_13_09).

Either way, don't combine them, or you can confuse your `make` utility, not to mention yourselves.